# easy google signin identification for php backend

Tags: php, google-signin

I have been struggling for a week with google sign-in authentication for php *without* deep composer installs.  answer follows to comply with question/answer format.

Comment: Not really a question here. Answering your own questions is encouraged. You should edit this question to make it a question, and then post your answer. It does appear it might be helpful to future readers, but as is, it violates the format of this site and is off topic

Answer (score 1):

I went down many wrong ends, although the final result is simple.  I will share it for others.  I am not an expert in any of the tools here, so improvements are welcome.

first, the html5 that is posted to the user:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <title>demonstration of google sign-in for php</title>


    <!-- you must add your own value here -->
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="<yourletterstring>.apps.googleusercontent.com">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>

    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>

    <script>
      function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
        console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
        $('#gid').html(profile.getId());
        $('#gemail').html(profile.getEmail());
        $('#gimg').attr("src", profile.getImageUrl());
        $('#gname').html(profile.getName());
        $('#gstatus').html("logged in");
        $('#gstatus').attr("style", "color:green");

        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        $('#gtoken').html(id_token);

        clickurl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token='+id_token;
        $('#gtokenurl').html('<a href="'+clickurl+'">click here</a>');

        $('#fidtoken').attr("value", id_token);  // passing into form

        $('#showresults').attr("display", "block"); // not working.
      }


      function signOut() {
        var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        auth2.signOut().then(function () {
          console.log('User signed out.');
          $('#gid').html("");
          $('#gemail').html("");
          $('#gimg').removeAttr("src");
          $('#gname').html("");
          $('#gstatus').html("logged out");
          $('#gstatus').attr("style", "color:red");

          $('#gtoken').html("");
          $('#gtokenurl').html("");

          $('#showresults').attr("display", "none"); // not working
          $('#showresults').attr("visibility", "hidden");
        });
      }

    </script>

    <style>td { padding:1ex; }</style>

  </head>

  <body style="margin:3em; background-color:khaki">

    <h1> demonstration of google sign-in for php </h1>

    <p> This is a working example of google sign in for a php website.  Start reading <a href="https://developers.google.com/identit
y/sign-in/web/devconsole-project">Google Sign-in For Websites</a>.  In particular, link in your developers console.</p>

    <p> In this javascript code, you only ever change one value above:
      <pre>
    &lt;meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="&lt;your value here&gt;.apps.googleusercontent.com"&gt;
      </pre>



    <h2> login button </h2>

    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
    <a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>


    <div id="showresults">  <!-- not working suppression -->

      <h2> results in javascript, not secure from server perspective </h2>

      <form method="POST" action="googlereturn.php">
    <input id="fidtoken" type="hidden" name="idtoken" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Pass Results To PHP" style="font-size:xx-large;margin:1ex;" />
      </form>

      <table id="showresults">
    <tr> <td>ID: </td> <td id="gid"></td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>Name: </td> <td id="gname"></td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>Img: </td> <td> <img id="gimg" /> </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>Email: </td> <td id="gemail"> </td> </tr>
    <!-- <tr> <td>Token: </td> <td id="gtoken"> </td> </tr> -->
    <tr> <td>Token URL: </td> <td id="gtokenurl"> </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>Status: </td> <td id="gstatus"> </td> </tr>
      </table>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

for some reason, I cannot blink the html results out of existence when logged out, but this is a beauty blemish that can be ignored.

the recipient php googlereturn.php script now is

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> google php identification recipient </title>
    </head>

    <body style="margin:3em; background-color:khaki">

        <h1> google php identification recipient </h1>

        <?php

        echo "<pre> "; print_r($_POST); echo "</pre>";

        $checkendpoint= "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=";
        $checkurl= $checkendpoint.$_POST['idtoken'];

        echo "<h2> google identity </h2>\n";

        $v=file_get_contents($checkurl);

        echo "<pre>$v</pre>\n";

        ?>

    <p>(This identity information was sent directly from <?= $checkendpoint ?> and thus can be trusted.)</p>
</body>
</html>
```

that's it.  hard to believe that this associated with a week of banging my head against a wall.

hope it helps others.

/iaw